Mono.Cecil weaver wrong branch targets
I'm trying to use Mono.Cecil to weave in some instrumentation code into existing methods - basically just a log before all the sequence points. This is simple, I can iterate over all of the sequence points and insert an Ldstr to load the log text and a Call instruction to something like Console.WriteLine. To make sure that branch targets don't get missed out on this logging, I go through the instructions again, and patch each branch target to make sure that they now point to these preceding log instructions. In theory, this sounded simple and this is the weaver code I ended up with:
using Mono.Cecil;
using Mono.Cecil.Cil;
using Mono.Cecil.Rocks;

internal sealed class InstrumentationWeaver
{
    public static void WeaveInstrumentationCode(string assemblyLocation)
    {
        var readerParameters = new ReaderParameters { ReadSymbols = true };
        using var assemblyDefinition = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(assemblyLocation, readerParameters);
        var weaver = new InstrumentationWeaver(assemblyDefinition.MainModule);
        weaver.WeaveModule();
        assemblyDefinition.Write("WeaveOutput.dll");
    }

    private readonly ModuleDefinition weavedModule;

    private InstrumentationWeaver(ModuleDefinition weavedModule)
    {
        this.weavedModule = weavedModule;
    }

    private void WeaveModule()
    {
        foreach (var type in this.weavedModule.GetTypes()) this.WeaveType(type);
    }

    private void WeaveType(TypeDefinition type)
    {
        foreach (var method in type.Methods) this.WeaveMethod(method);
    }

    private void WeaveMethod(MethodDefinition method)
    {
        if (method.IsAbstract || method.IsPInvokeImpl || method.IsRuntime || !method.HasBody) return;

        var jumpTargetPatches = new Dictionary<int, Instruction>();
        var ilProcessor = method.Body.GetILProcessor();

        // Weave each instruction for instrumentation
        var sequencePoints = method.DebugInformation.SequencePoints;
        foreach (var sequencePoint in sequencePoints)
        {
            var instruction = this.WeaveInstruction(ilProcessor, sequencePoint);
            if (instruction is not null) jumpTargetPatches.Add(sequencePoint.Offset, instruction);
        }

        // Patch jump targets
        foreach (var instruction in ilProcessor.Body.Instructions)
        {
            this.PatchJumpTarget(instruction, jumpTargetPatches);
        }

        // Patch exception handlers
        foreach (var exceptionHandler in method.Body.ExceptionHandlers)
        {
            this.PatchExceptionHandler(exceptionHandler, jumpTargetPatches);
        }

        method.Body.OptimizeMacros();
    }

    private Instruction? WeaveInstruction(ILProcessor ilProcessor, SequencePoint sequencePoint)
    {
        if (sequencePoint.IsHidden) return null;

        // Get the instruction at the sequence point
        var instruction = ilProcessor.Body.Instructions.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Offset == sequencePoint.Offset);
        if (instruction is null) return null;

        // Insert the instrumentation code before the instruction
        return this.AddInstrumentationCode(ilProcessor, instruction, sequencePoint);
    }

    private Instruction AddInstrumentationCode(ILProcessor ilProcessor, Instruction before, SequencePoint sequencePoint)
    {
        // For now we just write a message to the console
        var message = $"Sequence point at {sequencePoint.Document.Url}:{sequencePoint.StartLine}";
        var writeLineMethod = this.weavedModule.ImportReference(typeof(System.Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", [typeof(string)]));
        var instructions = new[]
        {
            Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ldstr, message),
            Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Call, writeLineMethod),
        };
        foreach (var instruction in instructions) ilProcessor.InsertBefore(before, instruction);
        return instructions[0];
    }

    private void PatchExceptionHandler(ExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, IReadOnlyDictionary<int, Instruction> jumpTargetPatches)
    {
        this.PatchJumpTarget(exceptionHandler.TryStart, jumpTargetPatches);
        this.PatchJumpTarget(exceptionHandler.TryEnd, jumpTargetPatches);
        this.PatchJumpTarget(exceptionHandler.HandlerStart, jumpTargetPatches);
        this.PatchJumpTarget(exceptionHandler.HandlerEnd, jumpTargetPatches);
        this.PatchJumpTarget(exceptionHandler.FilterStart, jumpTargetPatches);
    }

    private void PatchJumpTarget(Instruction instruction, IReadOnlyDictionary<int, Instruction> jumpTargetPatches)
    {
        if (instruction.Operand is Instruction targetInstruction)
        {
            if (jumpTargetPatches.TryGetValue(targetInstruction.Offset, out var newTarget))
            {
                instruction.Operand = newTarget;
            }
        }
        else if (instruction.Operand is Instruction[] targetInstructions)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < targetInstructions.Length; i++)
            {
                if (jumpTargetPatches.TryGetValue(targetInstructions[i].Offset, out var newTarget))
                {
                    targetInstructions[i] = newTarget;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


It works for loops, if-else statements, but for some reason when I use an if-else in a for loop, the jump targets get completely messed up. The smallest example I could find where it messes up is weaving this:
public static class Class1
{
    public static void TestMethod()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
    }
}

While some branch targets seem to be correct in the generated IL, the jump back at the very end points to an address higher than the last instruction (picture from ILSpy):

Since loops and if-elses on their own work, I don't think it's particularly backwards jumps on their own that mess up the logic, but I could not figure out what it is.

So it turns out, Cecil won't handle changing short-form jumps, in case you have too much code injected. So first you need to call method.Body.SimplifyMacros(); before injecting, and method.Body.OptimizeMacros(); after being done. Weirdly enough the latter code was already present, a residue of trial and error.

Given your comment I've found that this question is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267480/does-mono-cecil-take-care-of-branches-etc-location. It puts some explanation on why it's required and how it works
